# In python's IDLE, when I enter a new line it doesn't tab back like normal

Tags: python, ide, editor, python-idle

**Relevant background information**

I'm not asking for any technical coding advice but how to use an IDE as
i've seen to encounter some sort of bug or of turned something on.

I'm coding Object-Oriented python in it's basic editor: Idle.

**Problem**

When I enter a new line, it doesn't tab back where relevant anymore
but where I was in the previous line, but in the next one.
Sometimes it goes even farther.

**What I've tried to do**

I looked everywhere on IDLE if it was some sort of option I've accidentally
turned on. I've restarted IDLE completely multiple times.

**What I'm asking for**

Does any python programming know what this is and how to turn it off.

Comment: Have you an extra open parenthesis (or bracket/brace) on the line before the unwanted indent?

Comment: @KyleMeade On a side note, use PyCharm it's much better.

Comment: Keep in mind that IDEs aren't strictly necessary - I code with Notepad++ and a command prompt.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 _Gasp!_ Dun, dun, **dun**!

Comment: It's either un-closed `(` or `[`, or it's that you didn't use a colon where you should have (e.g., `for`, `def`, etc.)

Comment: Unless you post a transcript of what you're doing, we're just making wild guesses.

Comment: I am an IDLE maintainer and I cannot really understand your problem statement, especially "but where I was in the previous line, but in the next one.".  As Barmar said, edit your question to include example editor input.  Mark it as 'code'.  Also, what version of Python? And what OS?

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi Stackoverflow is not the place for free-floating opinions.  Without know *exactly* what Kyle typed, you cannot know whether and how any other editor would respond differently and whether the difference, if any, would be better.

Comment: IDLE has a 'smart indent' feature that usually works great.  I recently fixed one bug that I know about, in typing multiline strings with indents, as in docstrings.  When indent acts 'unexpectly' for me, in the editor, I means that I mis-typed something.  Or perhaps you do not understand what rules it is following.  It is impossible to know without knowing *exactly* what you type.  If there is another bug, I want to know so I can try to fix it.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I haven't revisited this thread because as I was coding it simply just resolved. To specify the problem as much as i can: No matter where I was in any script, where I was inside any block of code, when I pressed enter to type code into the next line, the exact character position in the row stayed the same. Normally, if you were say typing an if statement, than you entered, it would go to the next line but the character position in the row would be tabbed. Though when I had this issue, the exact position in the row, stayed the same.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy entered as in carriage return

Comment: Perhaps you had an unmatched opener, as in this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189282/python-idle-file-editor-thinks-i-want-more-auto-indent-than-i-do